# VirtualBox: deleted everything except base .vdi and .vbox

Tags: virtualbox

Im not sure if this belongs here, but anyways:
I deleted my whole snapshot folder for a debian guest system (I needed space and didnt think about it one second), now only the .vdi (around 10 GB) and .vbox of the base remain.
I obviously cant boot it, and despite finding some possible fixes when you only deleted snapshots, i dont know how i would implement them, since i only have this one .vdi and no other parent or child files anymore.

Is there any hope to retrieve my data? It is quite much, sadly.

Comment: Have you looked at recovery tools like Recuva ? https://www.ccleaner.com/recuva

Comment: Are you on Windows?

Comment: can recuva (or any program) read the `.vdi` ? And yes I am on windows. I also tried recuva for the snapshots, but they didnt show up.